# Laravel 5 Eloquent Model Results

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using eloquent model to retrieve data from database.My query

```
$tests_details = Previous_Mocks::where($data)->orderBy('sno', 'desc')->get();
```

As of my knowledge `$tests_details` will return array of objects(results) but when i echo `is_array($tests_details)` it is returning false which means it's not an array but when i echo `count($test_details)` it is showing the correct count.See below code

```
foreach ($tests_details as $td)
                {
                    echo is_object($td);
                    echo "<br/>";
                }
```

it is returing 1 for `is_object($td)`. When i print `$tests_details` using `print_r` function below is the output i am getting
[image]

and when is echo `$tests_details[0]->edate` it is showing proper output and everything working fine. But i want to know why the **eloquent** returned the data in the format shown in image instead of normal objects. I am new to laravel and currently using laravel 5.0 any explanation is appreciable.

Comment: @Mayanak explained it very clearly for your question. But if you ever want the results as array then try, $tests_details = Previous_Mocks::where($data)->orderBy('sno', 'desc')->toArray();

Answer (score 3):

The data return by `Previous_Mocks` model is a collection object.

> All multi-result sets returned by Eloquent are instances of the 
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection object, including results
>   retrieved via the get method or accessed via a relationship. The
>   Eloquent collection object extends the Laravel base collection, so it
>   naturally inherits dozens of methods used to fluently work with the
>   underlying array of Eloquent models.

However, collections are much more powerful than arrays and expose a variety of map / reduce operations that may be chained using an intuitive interface.

[Eloquent Collection Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections)

Comment: suppose if i am getting 10000 or even more rows from database in the format shown in above image(eloquent collection object) is it efficient ?

Comment: Yes, it is efficient